# Linux version sort; letters first

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, sorting, text-manipulation

GNU `sort -V` is great for sorting IP adresses. Unfortunately it throws all lines with leading letters (as opposed to numbers) to the bottom of the pile. Is there a way around  it?

<sup>Note:

• 192.168.0.103 is missing because it's the local host.

• MACs/HW addresses have been changed.</sup>

---

#### • cat

```
user@host:~$ cat /proc/net/arp
```

```
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.0.106    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.1      0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.101    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.104    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.110    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.108    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.107    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.102    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.105    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.100    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.109    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
```

---

#### • sort -V

```
user@host:~$ sort -V /proc/net/arp
```

```
192.168.0.1      0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.100    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.101    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.102    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.104    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.105    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.106    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.107    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.108    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.109    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
192.168.0.110    0x1         0x2         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        wlan0
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
```

---

Answer (score 4):

Here's one technique to keep the header at the top: redirect the file, and from the stream, consume the first line, then give the rest of the lines to sort.

```
{ IFS= read -r header; echo "$header"; sort -V; } < /proc/net/arp
```

Comment: hmm, that's, a lot, of, commas.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll just leave it for a bit in case someone has something more appropriate. If not, I'll give it the big green tick.